# How to find Element hidden in Cross-Origin Iframe

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Please, I need help to click on the <kbd>Accept cookies</kbd> of https://www.screwfix.com that appeared on the launch of Chrome browser. I discovered through the Selector hub that the element is inside a cross-origin `iframe`. I watched Sanjay Kumar's Selector Hub method of dealing with cross-origin `iframe` on YouTube. The result I am getting is `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException`. Please I need your help

```
public class Framework {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/Julius 2023 workspace/Laptop123/PassDriver/chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeOptions option=new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
         
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(option);
        driver.get("https://www.screwfix.com");
        
        
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
       driver.switchTo().frame("thirdPartyCheckerFrame");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Accept Cookies']")).click();
       driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  
}
```

RESULT: Below is the exception, I have tried different method, I cannot click on "Accept cookies" to allow me to proceed.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id thirdPartyCheckerFrame
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.17'
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below working code with explanation:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.screwfix.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
// below line will create an object of WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(15)); 

// below line will wait and switch into the desired iframe      
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='trustarc_cm']")));
// below line eill wait and click on Accept Cookie button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Accept Cookies']"))).click();
// below line will come out of iframe
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept the answer if it has resolved your issue.